# Import Error when using pandas_datareader.data using Spyder in Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, spyder, pandas-datareader

When importing `pandas_datareader.data as web`, I am getting the following error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'assert_raises_regex' from 'pandas.util.testing'

I am using Spyder from the Anaconda Navigator and I have tried updating Spyder, Anaconda and made sure I had the latest version of pandas

I am new to python so I might be missing something...

Comment: try to import numpy, to install it use "pip3 install numpy" to use it: "numpy.testing.assert_raises_regex()"

Comment: thanks for your reply ! I tried what you suggested but it does not seem to work. To clarify I am trying to access data from the Fred API using pandas datareader

Comment: Installing NumPy with pip is a bad idea if you're using Conda. Can you share the contents of the environment, as well as how you installed the packages?

Answer (score 0):

You should install the latest version of `pandas-datareader` from anaconda as the warning says`pandas.util.testing` is being deprecated in favor of `pandas.testing`. A look at the source [https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/blob/master/pandas_datareader/compat/**init**.py](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/blob/master/pandas_datareader/compat/__init__.py) shows the `pandas_datareader.compat` module using `pandas.testing` instead.